# How do I use Readline input to write a IF/ELSE statement?

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program that accepts users numerical input then output predetermined messages. My question is after I convert the user input from a string to int, how do I use their input in a IF/ELSE statement.

Here's what I have so far:

string UserInput;
            Console.Write ("Enter a random number? ");

```
        UserInput =Console.ReadLine();
        int x = Convert.ToInt32 (UserInput);
        Console.WriteLine (" You entered: " + UserInput);

        int x;

        if (x < 0) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine (" Error message: Out of range: Enter a number between 0 and 200");
        }

        { else if (x >100)

            Console.WriteLine (" You are above average");
        }

        { else if (x == 100)

            Console.WriteLine (" You are average");
        }

        {
            else if (x < 100)

            Console.WriteLine (" Sorry but you are below average");
        }
```

Comment: When you write 
`int x = Convert.ToInt32 (UserInput);`
you do not need to write
    `int x;` 
after that.

Comment: How do I assign a value to int x that reflects the user input from the Readline?

Comment: Rename last `x` to `x1` or something like that. Then assign `x1=x;`. That's it.

Comment: @DeveloperAlicia : you have done that already with _int x = Convert.ToInt32 (UserInput);_ but this would cause an exception for invalid input, see my solution for an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opening parentheses for the else statements should be on the line after the else, not before it. Also your initial if statement needs to check for > 200 too, according to the message printed.

You can also add error checking by using the Int32.TryParse method like this.

```
string UserInput; 
int x;
Console.Write ("Enter a random number? ");
UserInput =Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine (" You entered: " + UserInput);

if (! Int32.TryParse(UserInput, out x))
  {
     Console.WriteLine ("Invalid data input");
  }
else if ((x < 0) || (x>200))
    {
        Console.WriteLine (" Error message: Out of range: Enter a number between 0 and 200");
    }
else if (x >100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (" You are above average");
    }
else if (x == 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (" You are average");
    }
else if (x < 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (" Sorry but you are below average");
    }
```

Comment: I am quite sure he doesn't know what he exactly want here

Comment: I do think reading a simple tutorial on C# if..then..else may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest one way. This way is cleaner and contains error handling. I think you should pass a C# tutorial. Cheers.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a random number? ");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" You entered: " + userInput);

        try
        {
            int input = int.Parse(userInput);
            PrintMessage(input);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Error message: Your input is not a number");
        }
    }

    private static void PrintMessage(int input)
    {
        if (input < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Error message: Out of range: Enter a number between 0 and 200");
        }
        else if (input > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" You are above average");
        }
        else if (input == 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" You are average");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Sorry but you are below average");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to input directly in to the function :

```
    if (Convert.ToInt32 (UserInput) < 0) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine (" Error message: Out of range: Enter a number between 0 and 200");
    }
    else if Convert.ToInt32 (UserInput) >100) {

        Console.WriteLine (" You are above average");
    }

    else if (Convert.ToInt32 (UserInput) == 100) {

        Console.WriteLine (" You are average");
    }

    else if (Convert.ToInt32 (UserInput) < 100) {

        Console.WriteLine (" Sorry but you are below average");
    }
```